# React.js onClick return event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I had properly working link with JS `onclick` attribute on a CMS, the code looked like this:

`<a class="button is-success" onclick="return klaro.show();">click</a>`

it was opening the model window.
Now I'm trying to replicate this on an old `React.js` project.
I remember, that there are a few language notations, but as I'm not working at all with this language it's difficult for me.

I've these kind of links:

```
    <li><a href="#link">{t('Link')}</a></li>
    <li><a class="button is-success" onclick="return klaro.show();">{t('cookie choice')}</a></li>
```

But since it's `React` the last link is not working. I tried to change it to `<a className="button is-success" onClick={() => "return klaro.show();"}>člick</a>` but the `onClick` event is absent once the page is rendered.

How should it be done correctly with this notation?

Comment: React doesn't `onclick` attributes to the html. It rather does event delegation. Also, your `onClick` prop is invalid. It should be more like this `onClick={() => klaro.show()}`, but I think you are trying to do something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Use this

```
<li><a href="#link">{t('Link')}</a></li>
<li><a class="button is-success" onClick={klaro.show}>{t('cookie choice')}</a></li>
```

#### Or Use Like This

```
<li><a href="#link">{t('Link')}</a></li>
<li><a class="button is-success" onClick={() => klaro.show()}>{t('cookie choice')}</a></li>
```

Comment: You're mixing Vanilla JS and React.

Comment: Thank you, the `<a class="button is-success" onClick={() => klaro.show()}>{t('click')}</a>` works as expected

Comment: Yes for react you have to use lots of keyword differently. See React Official Documentation

for example of some attributes
class -> className
for -> htmlFor
onclick -> onClick
onfocus -> onFocus

Answer (score 1):

Pass a reference to of `klaro.show` to the `onClick` prop. This will tell React to call the `klaro.show` method when you click.

```
<a className="button is-success" onClick={klaro.show}>člick</a>
```

Comment: does`onClick={klaro.show}` behave the same as `onClick={() => klaro.show()}` return-wise?

Comment: No, `onClick={() => klaro.show()}` will return the result from `klaro.show()`, `onClick={klaro.show}` will not. But you don't need to use `return` as you're not doing anything with the result that `klaro.show()` produces.

Comment: they might return `false` to prevent default action of the `<a>` tag;

Comment: The anchor tag doesn't have an `href` attribute. So it wouldn't do anything otherwise by default.

Answer (score 1):

People already answered the question correctly; but there is another dirty unclean way to do that as well; **I don't recommend it**, just for your information:

```
<li dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: `
   <a class="button is-success" onclick="return klaro.show();">click</a>`
}}></li>
```